Applying custom queries to multiple databases for PostgreSQL in Datadog
We're using RDS with PostgreSQL engine v12.17 and integration with Datadog. We have multiple databases and have multiple custom queries for these databases.
Currently, there is a lot of duplication, because for the same custom query but a different database (on the same host), we have a separate entry in the postgres.yaml file:
init_config: 
instances:
  - host: host1
    port: 5432
    username: ...
    password: ...
    dbname: database1
    custom_queries:
      - metric_prefix: ...
        query: select ...;
        columns: ...
 
  - host: host1
    port: 5432
    username: ...
    password: ...
    dbname: database2
    custom_queries:
      - metric_prefix: ...
        query: select ...;
        columns: ...

As we have multiple hosts, databases and custom queries, the YAML manifests get quite complex, with some of them exceeding the size limits for ArgoCD & ETCD in k8s (we're deploying Datadog as Helm Chart in Kubernetes). Splitting these entries into separate files is also unbearable, as we would need to manage hundreds of those.
I saw in the conf.example.yaml for Postgres there is a key called database_autodiscovery, which when enabled, takes list of the databases to monitor.
Unfortunately, it seems like dropping the dbname in favor of this autodiscovery option does not make the queries execute on all of the included databases, as I received the "relation ... does not exist", which denotes that the database for the query was still taken from the dbname field (which omitted, defaults to the postgres database, which indeed does not have said relation).
I tried to group multiple databases under the same custom_queries using database_autodiscovery as follows:
instances:
  - host: host1
    port: 5432
    username: ...
    password: ...
    database_autodiscovery:
      enabled: true
      include:
        - db1$
        - db2$
        - db3$
    custom_queries:
     - metric_prefix: ...
       query: select ...;

Is there a possibility to provide multiple databases for the custom queries to execute in under a single instances[] entry?

I needed this feature as well. My initial thought was to use yaml anchors but Datadog support said that it is still a feature request. So I ended up implementing it myself.
https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/pull/17993
Edit: The changes have been merged and are available in the postgres integration version 19.1.0 - https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/master/postgres/CHANGELOG.md#1910--2024-08-09

It's a shame that MySQL database integration has this global_custom_queries functionality supported, but not the postgreSQL.
Finally, I came up with the custom solution, which just takes a postgresql configuration file with list od databases and just multiplies the manifest X times, depending on how many databases should use the custom query.
Hopefully the change will be merged quickly! Thanks for the information that there is a pending change for that.
